# what is the basis for $A_3(T_p(\mathbb{R^4}))$.

Tags: manifolds

Let $x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4 $ be the coordinates on $\mathbb{R^4}$ and $p$ a point in $\mathbb{R^4}$. Write down a basis for the vector space $A_3(T_p(\mathbb{R^4}))$.

I have no idea what is the basis for $k$- linear alternating spaces over vector spaces. 
Can somebody explain it to me. I found some multiindex notaion in a book when looking for basis for space $A_k(V)$, but did not understood it. Please explain.

$\textbf{Notations-}$

Here $ T_p(\mathbb{R^4})$ is tangent space at a point $p$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $A_3( T_p(\mathbb{R^4}))$ means space of all 3-linear function (or also called alternating $3$-tensors, or $3$-covectors) on $ T_p(\mathbb{R^4})$

Comment: Maybe you can explain the meaning of $A_3$ and $T_p$.

Comment: @mvw done. see edit

Answer (score 0):

Number of elements in the basis of $A_3(T_p(\mathbb R^4))= \ _4C_3.$ Basis for $A_3(T_p(\mathbb R^4))=\{dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3, dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^4, dx^2 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4, dx^1 \wedge dx^3 \wedge dx^4 \}.$